# Only Ignore nulls on deserialization in Json.Net

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

When I have the following model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        FirstName = string.Empty;
        LastName = string.Empty;
    }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string FirstName {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

And that works great for when I'm posting data:

```
// {
//    firstName: null,
//    lastName: null
// }

public int Post([FromBody]Customer customer)
{
    var firstName = customer.FirstName; //  <-- value is ""
}
```

The problem with this is that if the developer forgets in this system to initialize the data, then the response structure will leave it out:

```
public Customer
{
    FirstName = "";
}

// {
//    firstName: ''
// }
```

Basically, I don't want the values to be null but I also don't want to require the user to add an optional parameter in the request. I can't use `[Require]` because it doesn't satisfy that second part.

How it is set up now the onus is on the developer to initialize the property or else it will be omitted. Is there a way to accomplish this so that it only ignores for deserialization and not serialization?

Comment: What happens if you use `Include` instead? Documentation states that it will exclude it on deserialization if it is null and `Ignore` is used: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm

Comment: @RickyHartmann Essentially I want to use Include only for serialization so all my properties are guaranteed to be there but Ignore on deserialization so if the caller explicitly sets a property to null it won't overwrite the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I might rephrase your question, you appear to be asking, *How can I have a property of a type that always has a default, non-null value even when set to `null` when deserializing JSON or when uninitialized in application code?*  If this rephrasing is correct, this can be handled by the type itself by using explicit rather than automatic properties:

```
public class Customer
{
    string firstName = "";
    string lastName = "";

    public Customer() { }

    public string FirstName { get { return firstName; } set { firstName = value ?? ""; } }

    public string LastName { get { return lastName; } set { lastName = value ?? ""; } }
}
```

`FirstName` and `LastName` are now guaranteed to be non-null no matter how the `Customer` class is constructed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this solution still puts the responsibility on the developer to check for null using the null coalesce operator. I was thinking more If I were able to ignore a null property on deserialization but on the way back to a client the object should look complete, as in all properties are serialized even if they are null so the json looks like the complete object.

Comment: @TomFobear - please clarify your requirements then.  1) What do you want to see in the returned JSON for your class -- `null` or `""`?  2) What level of burden on your developers is acceptable?  How is making the developer add `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` to each property more or less burdensome than making them add a `??` in each property?

Comment: I suppose it is not and it does satisfy the requirement of it serializing the property to json. Is there an attribute I can inherit that will be called by the deserializer though?

Comment: @TomFobear - is it the case that you *always* want `null` strings to be ignored when deserializing and returned as empty strings when serializing?  Or is it class and property specific?

Comment: @TomFobear - to clarify, if you want a global solution that automatically maps `null` string values to empty string values for all string-type properties without placing any requirements developers of specific classes, this can be done using a [custom contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm).

Comment: A custom contract resolver may be what we are looking for... most of the values in our schema are not null but we'll have to take a look at the design. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @TomFobear - got one that works if you want to ask another question.